# How to use ArcGIS JavaScript API's map.centerAndZoom()?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms

I'm trying to get the map to move and zoom in to a point when a function is executed. Point gets selected, but without zoom. Interestingly when I zoom in to a random location and then execute the method I'll get zoomed out a bit and moved to correct position.

```
drawPointToMap(true);
```

Code:

```
function drawPointToMap(zoom) {
var lat = $('#id_latitude').val();
var lon = $('#id_longitude').val();

if (lat != '' && lon != '' && !isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lon)) {
    try {
        var point = new esri.geometry.Point({
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: lon
        });
        mapHandler.drawToMap(point);
        if (zoom) {
            console.log('center and ZOOM');
            mapHandler.map.centerAndZoom(point, 10);
        } else {
            mapHandler.map.centerAt(point);
        }
    } catch(err) {}
}
```

}

Console prints 'center and ZOOM' as expected, but doesn't actually zoom. I'm displaying a WMS layer without a basemap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used similar functionality in my map.

-Created doIdentify() function and called on click event.

```
function doIdentify(evt) {
         app.map.centerAndZoom(evt.mapPoint,6);
                          }
```

You can check sample code at [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GU7Vk/)

Please let us know if you get any error message.